# Nodejs: simple scaling

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is a somewhat theoretical question to help me understand things better.

I have a page that allows people to update information to a mongodb as follows:

```
 {name: john}
 {address: home}
 {email: john@johnsfamily.com}
```

And I have a script which allows other people in the family to add their details too like:

```
 {name: sarah}
 {address: home}
 {email: sarah@johnsfamily.com}
```

Then I would like anyone with the email: xxx@johnsfamily.com to be able to access the database.

My question is, what is the best way of scaling this to allow many familes to use the facility to store and see their family information without other people seeing it too?

I have been doing this using the mongo find function to only allow users access to documents with the same email domain, but I wonder whether that constitutes good practice?

Is this recommended practice for a small scale multiple user setup? I am looking for a fairly secure but simple solution.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing,create a **master schema** where you can create a schema for storing the details of head of the family(or the related person), and in the **family schema**, for every family member detail, you can store the id of master along with their data, going this way you are making a link between a master account and other accounts. If you want to search all the family members associated to a master account, simply pass **`db.collection.find({master: masterId}, function(err, data){});`**. I consider it a better approach as if you use email, passing string will be a little costly for DB. Basically using **objectId** will make query work faster then string.

It is a safer and a faster approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems rather limiting to assume that all members of a family have both a unique email domain and all use that same domain.  Our family, for example, has four different email accounts on three different domains and two of the domains are not custom domains (like gmail.com and yahoo.com).

What I think would likely work better would be to have the first one to set up a family be the "administrator" for that family and they can then add email addresses of other people (presumably in their family) that they want to be able to contribute to this particular data set.

So, each "account" would have one master administrator and then a list of other users who were allowed to contribute to that account.  There are several different ways to structure that in the database.